# Acccessing own schema/tables of an H2 embedded database via DB tool?

Tags: database, h2

I have a web application using an embedded (in-memory) H2 database. It seems like the H2 DB is set up correctly on Tomcat startup (no errors in server log), but when accessing the DB (through the application) it seems to be "empty" (no application tables nor data available, even though the log states that they have been created/inserted).

How can I check the H2 DB is really set up or not? I've been trying to connect to the DB using a DB tool (e.g. H2 console, DB Visualizer) but I am not sure about the proper DB connection string or username/pw as it is not explicitly defined in the project.

By raising the log level in the server log, I could at least retrieve this information:

```
Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:myDataSource;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1]
```

Not sure though whether I am really connected or not because I could pass any user/pw combination and can still "connect"? Probably it's not the right way, because I can only retrieve schemas INFORMATION_SCHEMA and PUBLIC on the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a memory database, even a named one, because as soon as the last SQL connection using it is closed, the database will be purged. If you open it again, the only thing you'll see is information_schema tables and views.

I suggest you use embedded mode instead: the database will be persisted, and you can later on open it in another process, a DB viewer, or even in tcp mode if you started H2 server.

As you're using Tomcat, I just wrote today an answer to a similar issue (Embedding an H2 Database within the WEB-INF Directory).

Might be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638808/3956551